# Backbone.js Pushstate: true not returning callback function

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

I am pretty new to backbone js and I am having some problem getting the pushstate functionality of my app to work. Here is an eg of my route:

```
var TodoRouter = new (Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": "index",
        "item/add": "AddTodoItem",
        "list/add": "AddTodoList"
    },
    AddTodoItem: function() {
        //e.preventDefault();
        alert("add new item");
    },
    AddTodoList: function(e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        alert("add new list");
    },
    Start: function(){
            //note: my directory structure is localhost/playground/todo/
        Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: "/playground/todo/"});
    }, 
    initalize: function(){

    }, 
    index: function(){
        var todoListView = new TodoListView({ collection: TodoItemCollection });
    }
}));
```

Here is how I call my route:

```
$(function() {
    TodoRouter.Start();
});
```

And lastly here is how I call a link:

```
<a href="#list/add" id="newList">New List</a>
```

The problem that I am running into is that when I call the link, the page stays the same, no alert and the browser displays:

```
http://localhost/playground/todo/#list/add
```

Now here is the funny part, if I refresh the page, the url become:

```
http://localhost/playground/todo/list/add
```

and I get the alert. So I have a feeling I am missing a key point somewhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have `pushState: true` and that's why it preferred the slash `/` instead of hash `#`

Either change that or remove the hash

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use Backbone Routes and html5 pushState.

As the backbone documentation said:

> "if you have a route of /documents/100, your web server must be able
>   to serve that page, if the browser visits that URL directly."

So if you want to trigger some functions through uri (`localhost/webapp/#about`) you just need to use Backbone Routes. 
If you want to use Backbone Routes and pushState, you'll need a back-end to answer requests made to your readable url (`localhost/webapp/about`) and need to use backbone.navigate method to avoid the browser understand `<a href="#someRoute">` as a html anchor.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970933/render-backbone-view-on-click-via-router-push-state/18971232#18971232) you can see a complete example

**You can't trigger your route, because when `pushState:true` the `href="#route"` has the same behavior as a html anchor.**